# Color fill on background png image using css only

Tags: css

A slider plugin on a Wordpress website produces:

`background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) url(../images/black_icon.png) no-repeat center center;`

Is it possible to change to color of the background image, using only CSS?

If I change the `background-color` it are not the strokes in the image that change color, but instead the background colour of the background image. Instead, I would like the line strokes of the image to change color (using only CSS). Is this possible?

Comment: See [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter).

Comment: No, because that color is embedded in the image file itself and there's not much CSS can change about that.

Comment: You can only change the `opacity` of the image, not the color.